# Should I use @staticmethod if I don't have an __init__ method for a class?

Tags: python

I am building a menu system where each specific menu is implemented as a python class. However, the classes do not need a `__init__` function and giving them one would waste space because I have many classes and each one is relatively small. Here are two examples:

```py
class CLOCK_TIME_INCREMENT_MENU:
    optionl1 = "Clock increment:" 
    options = [str(x) + " second(s)" for x in range(0, 21, 2)] # Menu options (displayed to user)

    def yes(board): # Called when user presses "yes"
        durations = range(0, 21, 2)
        board.clock_time_increment = durations[board.co] # board.co is the menu option the user selected
        board.start_game()

class USE_CLOCK_MENU:
    optionl1 = None
    options = [["Use clock?", ""]]

    def yes(board):
        board.use_clock = True
        board.menu_stack.append(CLOCK_TIME_MENU) # Add next part of menu to menu stack

    def no(board): # Called when the user presses "no"
        board.use_clock = False
        board.start_game()
```

I then have a loop in a different class (the `board` class) that reads the top menu class in `board.menu_stack` and displays the options from the class. When the user clicks the yes or no buttons, the loop calls the appropriate methods in the menu class.

So I have two questions: First, the methods in the menu classes *are* static methods, so should I use the `@staticmethod` decorator, as I normally would? I think all it does is remove the first instance argument from method calls on methods in classes that have `__init__` functions, so I shouldn't use it for the menu class methods. Am I correct?

Second, is there anything wrong with the way I am using the classes without `__init__` methods to structure my menu? Is there a better data structure I could use to get the same functionality?

Thanks and please ask for clarifications if you need them!

Answer (score 1):

They will have a default `__init__` function that do nothing:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f5d84b8b828>
>>> Foo().__init__
<method-wrapper '__init__' of Foo object at 0x7f5d84b8b908>
>>> Foo.__init__
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>
```

You can use the `@staticmethod` so you will not need to instantiate the class in order to use the methods (Your class will behave as a short of namespace). But the pythonic way of doing this would be to have a simple module for each one with variables and functions.

This could be an example of structure:
your_project
... menu
      ... clock_time_increment.py
      ... use_clock.py

In `clock_time_increment.py`:

```
OPTION_L1 = "Clock increment:" 
OPTIONS = [str(x) + " second(s)" for x in range(0, 21, 2)] # Menu options (displayed to user)
```

The other module in the same style.

```
def yes(board): # Called when user presses "yes"
    durations = range(0, 21, 2)
    board.clock_time_increment = durations[board.co] # board.co is the menu option the user selected
    board.start_game()
```

Comment: However I don't need to instantiate the class anyway..... I just call CLASS.yes(self) from my Board instance for example...

Comment: Ah. I didn't think of using modules. Maybe I'll do that. Although I don't exactly like the idea of making a new file for each and every part of my menu...

Comment: @scitronboy, I think Its kind of overengineered. Why use classes for not encapsulating attributtes and operations?

Comment: @scitronboy, well you can export all of it from the menu pakage, so you will be able to do, `from menu import *`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Why use classes for not encapsulating attributtes and operations?"

Comment: @scitronboy, well the major power in classes is that you can encapsulate the attributes and operate over them, but in this case you are just using plain functions and attributtes over a common name, which is how modules behave anyway, so you are having an extra layer of abstraction that then you do not really use. Sorry if I am not being clear in the explanation here.